# Zucchini Run: Could not find anchor for screen

Tags: ssh, anchor, zucchini

When i run "**zucchini run features/**" on my local mac machine, the command is getting executed but when am running the same through remote ssh to the same machine it is giving "**Could not find anchor for screen 'PINScreen' on line 615 of feature.js**" error.

error is as follows:

```
zucchini run features/
Failed to authorize rights (0x2) with status: -60007.
Failed to authorize rights (0x2) with status: -60007.
2013-12-12 18:37:23.983 ScriptAgent[3473:2f07] CLTilesManagerClient: initialize, sSharedTilesManagerClient

2013-12-12 18:37:23.983 ScriptAgent[3473:2f07] CLTilesManagerClient: init
2013-12-12 18:37:23.984 ScriptAgent[3473:2f07] CLTilesManagerClient: reconnecting, 0x97f4030
2013-12-12 18:37:24.147 ScriptAgent[3473:2f07] AX Lookup problem! 1102 com.apple.iphone.axserver:3467
2013-12-12 18:37:24.156 ScriptAgent[3473:2f07] AX Lookup problem! 1102 com.apple.iphone.axserver:3467
2013-12-12 13:07:24 +0000 Debug: target.setDeviceOrientation("1")
2013-12-12 13:07:29 +0000 Error: Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: Could not find anchor for screen 'PINScreen' on line 615 of feature.js
2013-12-12 13:07:29 +0000 Stopped: Script was stopped by the user
Instruments Trace Complete (Duration : 17.254980s; Output : /Users/jebastalin/Desktop/ZucchiniNew/FileViewer/instrumentscli0.trace)
1..1
not ok 1 - feature
    1..0
    Bail out! Instruments run error

TAP report generated to /tmp/zucchini.t
HTML report generated to /tmp/zucchini_report.html
[SSH] exit-status: 1
```

So, hoe can I successfully run the "zucchini run" command from remote login?

Answer (score 0):

put Show elements above your zucchini script where you call the screen 
this may solve your problem .

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if I encounter lines similar to the following in the logs:

```
2014-05-01 14:17:43.915 ScriptAgent[14082:2f07] AX Lookup problem! 1102 com.apple.iphone.axserver:14073
2014-05-01 14:17:43.925 ScriptAgent[14082:2f07] AX Lookup problem! 1102 com.apple.iphone.axserver:14073
```

This will cause good code to fail. The remedy I've been using is to quit the iOS simulator (and also Instruments.app). After closing both out, re-run Zucchini, and without changing any of my code everything now works.

I can't say that this is *the* fix, but it has worked all the times I can remember.